# Can we combine nested integrals into one integral?

Tags: integration

If we are given a double integral,

$$\int_c^d{\int_a^b{f(x,y) \, \mathrm dx}\, \mathrm dy}$$

can we convert this into a single integral, i.e.

$$\int_{a_2}^{b_2}{f(z)\, \mathrm dz}$$

...where $a_2$ and $b_2$ can be whatever makes the procedure easiest.  I'm looking for a general procedure for doing this, so I can't really get more specific than this as far as concrete examples go, because I will use this on many different integrals.  The only thing in common that the integrals will probably have in common is that they are all Riemann integrals, or integrals that have no discontinuities.

Comment: As far as I know the answer is no. I'm reluctant to put that as an answer because I'm not big on measure theory, so there might be a clever trick I don't know about, but I have a feeling that even though you could express it as one "integral" (which is what I suspect ncmathsadist's answer is about), when it came to computing the thing you'd end up needing to do two integrals anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This double integral is actually over the box $[c,d]\times[a,b]$ where $\times$ is used in the cartesion product sense.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: $[c,d] \times [a,b] = \{(x,y)|x\in[c,d], y\in[a,b]\}$.

Comment: That's not a Riemann integral, though.