# Can someone demonstrate this integral with a cartesian product?

Tags: integration

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384711/can-we-combine-nested-integrals-into-one-integral), we can apparently get an integral:

$$\int_{a \times c}^{b \times d}\!{\left(1+e^{i(x+1/2y)}+e^{i(y)}\right)\,d(x \times y)}$$

...I'm not exactly sure that this integral is posed correctly.

I'm wondering how we can solve this integral.  Essentially, I'm wondering how we can solve an integral involving the caresian product.  **I'm trying to avoid a nested integral in this instance**, so I'm hoping that this will work.

Can someone show how to integrate this integral **in extreme detail**?

Comment: I think the answer to your prior question is incomplete, so this one doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @BenMillwood: Ok, thanks!

Comment: "I think" is to be taken seriously in that comment :) I'm not an expert in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to integrate in this case because there is no well-defined set upon which you are integrating. All you are stating is that the integral has to start at a certain point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and end at a certain point in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now with a certain class of functions, it turns out it doesn't matter which way you go from the start to end point, but in general it does matter which path is taken.